# How to pass variable from fixture in conftest.py to different test class

Tags: pytest

I have fixtue that found in conftest.py and I need to use the information from the fixture in different test class.

conftest.py:

```
@fixture(scope="module")
def init_environment():  
    ip1 = "1.2.3.4"
    ip2 = "1.2.3.5"
    ips_tuple = (ip1, ip2)
```

differemt test class:

```
class testClass():

    def test1(self, init_environment):
        ip_tuple_in_class = {here I want ips_tuple from the fixture}
```

Ho can I fetch the data in test class?

Comment: `return ips_tuple` in fixture. The returned value will then be passed to tests, e.g. `ip_tuple_in_class = init_environment` in test.

Comment: works good, thanks!

Comment: @hoefling Can you turn your comment into an answer so that GabiJava can accept it?

Comment: @xverges someone else has added an answer meanwhile, won't restate the same thing again just for the formality sake, but thanks for the reminder! I often forget to write an answer if the comment already helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Please try next one:

**conftest.py:**

```
@fixture(scope="module")
def init_environment():  
    ip1 = "1.2.3.4"
    ip2 = "1.2.3.5"
    ips_tuple = (ip1, ip2)
    return ips_tuple
```

**different test class:**

```
class fakeTests():

    def test_fake_1(self, init_environment):
        print(init_environment)
```